# Why the Underscores site advises against using Underscores as a parent theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to use [Underscores.me](http://underscores.me/) ( A Starter Theme for WordPress ) for my next WordPress Theme. But I am little bit confuse because they advises against using Underscores as a parent theme. And I want to create a parent theme wit Underscores. Please explain me.

Answer (score 1):

Because Underscores is a starter theme and not a theme framework like [Genesis](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/).

There's no need to keep it in this starter state. It was made as a bunch of files and code snippets to use in your new wordpress theme. You are free to remove what you don't need and add your own functions.

Although you can use it as a parent theme, but with a few tweaks like locating parent style.css file.

And a quote from Lister:

> _s doesn’t tell you how to do things, it gives you a start. Anything we add to it should also do that